# PC not going to sleep windows 7

Tags: sleep, power, mode

PC not going to sleep windows 7... Please help me come from this issue. 
Tried many basic steps to resolve this. But some services are stopping the PC not to sleep mode.
For ex : In my org, we have 100 PC means 50 PC's going to sleep mode, others are not going properly.
Is there any scripts available to resolve this? Or i need to check anything from my side? Pl help me friends.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as a script
**rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0**

however, it will hibernate instead of sleep if you don't turn the hibernation off.
Run CMD as Administrator and use **powercfg -hibernate off**